# Selenium Python simple automation task

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I have a truckload of trace files I'm trying to catalog. The idea is to open each one with "chrome://tracing" then save a screenshot. Screenshots are easy to catalog.

Here is the process:

1. start chrome = works
2. open "chrome://tracing" = works
3. open file <== missing part <- I need help with
4. save screenshot = works

There are 2 ways to open the file in chrome://tracing:

a) - use the "load" button, navigate to file and open
           Update: I was able to locate and click on the "Load" button using Selenium

```
 Now - need to handle the file open / loading ??
```

b) - drag and drop a trace file to the main part of the window - opens it
        [ no idea how to do this..]

Here is the actual code I have so far:

```
 from selenium import webdriver

 driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path
 driver.get("chrome://tracing");
 time.sleep(2) # Let the user actually see something

 # Find load button
 # or drop file to main window ?
 # Send the file location to the button

 file_location =  'C:\........json'

 driver.send_keys(file_location)  # don't know where to sent it :: idea from https://towardsdatascience.com/controlling-the-web-with-python-6fceb22c5f08

 time.sleep(15)     # some files are big - might take 15 seconds to load

 date_stamp = str(datetime.datetime.now()).split('.')[0]
 date_stamp = date_stamp.replace(" ", "_").replace(":", "_").replace("-", "_")
 file_name = date_stamp + ".png"
 driver.save_screenshot(file_name)
```

---

After some research and trial and error here is my final(?) working code

- located "Load" button and opened the file Open dialog
- used pywinauto to take care communication with the Open dialog
- saved a screenshot - using a unique filename generated from datestamp

---

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from pywinauto.application import Application
import datetime

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options) 
driver.get("chrome://tracing");
time.sleep(2) 

# Find load button
sdomele =  driver.find_element_by_tag_name("tr-ui-timeline-view")
ele = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot;",sdomele)
button_found = ele.find_element_by_id("load-button")
button_found.click()   # let's load that file

time.sleep(3)

# here comes the pywinauto part to take care communication with the Open file dialog
app = Application().connect(title='Open')    # connect to an existing window
dlg = app.window(title='Open')       # communicate with this window

#file_location = os.path.join(submission_dir, folder, file_name)

file_location =  "C:\\FILES2OPEN\\file01.json"
app.dlg.type_keys(file_location)    # txt goes to the "File Name" box

time.sleep(2)  #type is slow - this is just for safety
app.dlg.OpenButton.click()      # click the open button

time.sleep(15)   # some files might be big

# generate filename based on current time
date_stamp = str(datetime.datetime.now()).split('.')[0]
date_stamp = date_stamp.replace(" ", "_").replace(":", "_").replace("-", "_")
file_name = date_stamp + ".png"
driver.save_screenshot(file_name)   # save screenshot (just the "inner" part of the browser window / not a full screenshot)

time.sleep(2)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Are you aware of the `trace2html` utility? It may represent an alternative solution.. https://github.com/catapult-project/catapult/tree/master/tracing

Comment: I did hear about it. Unfortunately I was not able to make it work on my windows pc. Even if it works I still need to open each html file one by one to generate a screenshot (original goal).

Comment: Please do not provide solutions to use AutoIt  [to handle the file selection]. I don't see a point of using tools just for a part of the problem. With AutoIt I can easily solve the original problem - without using webdriver + selenium +  python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you were not able to find the load button is because its present in a [shadow dom](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/accessing-shadow-dom-elements-with-webdriver). So first you need to find the shadow dom using execute_script ,then locate the "load" button as usual. The following code worked for me :

```
sdomele =  _driver.find_element_by_tag_name("tr-ui-timeline-view")
ele = _driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot;",sdomele)
ele.find_element_by_id("load-button").click()
```